# I have come across in vector calculus. Using the property of Tensors We need to prove what is the final result of this equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, vector-fields, calculus

What is the result of this equation :
$$\nabla(\vec A \cdot \vec B )$$
Where, $\nabla$ is the del operator.

Try to solve using Tensor Properties.

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange. Right now your question is not following community guidelines. This site isn't to let other people answer your homework questions. Please read https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange. If you show what you did and at which point you got stuck you can still ask homework questions. If you don't do this your question migth get closed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec A\cdot\vec B$ is a scalar, so $\nabla$ here acts as the gradient. You can calculate this component wise
$$\nabla(\vec A\cdot\vec B)=\pmatrix{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\vec A\cdot\vec B)\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\vec A\cdot\vec B)\\\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\vec A\cdot\vec B)}$$
I think these kinds of problems are the most clear in Einstein notation. In Einstein notation everytime you see the same index twice you sum over them. For example $A_jB_j=\sum_{j=1}^3 A_jB_j$. Every index that isn't summed over can be seen as a vector (or tensor) component. This gives
$$\nabla(\vec A\cdot\vec B)_i=\partial_iA_jB_j$$
where $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. Expanding using the product rule gives
$$\nabla(\vec A\cdot\vec B)_i=A_j\partial_iB_j+B_j\partial_iA_j$$
Now you can recast Einstein notation back into vector calculus notation. To be honest for this particular problem it's quite hard to do so and normally I would stop here since it's not really illuminating. But let's power through. The gradient of a vector can be written as a matrix since it has two indices
$$(\nabla \vec A)_{i,j}=\partial_iA_j$$
Now we can write our answer as
$$(\nabla \vec A)\cdot\vec B+(\nabla \vec B)\cdot\vec A$$
or as
$$(\nabla \vec A)\cdot\vec B+\vec A\cdot(\nabla \vec B)^T$$